# ADODB Stream of binary file fails to write from SQL Azure

Tags: sql-server, azure, adodb

We have a Planned Maintenance System which stores and retrieves documents in a SQL database from an Access front end using ADODB Stream and SQL server authorisation. All works happily with a local database, but with SQL Azure the download fails. The connection opens OK but I get "Write To File failed, run time error 3004".
The same code works to the same location from a local server, so it's a permissions issue.
I've tried various locations for the file on the C drive, have given the folder all the permissions I can find and turned off the Firewall and Virus scanner.
Despite searching the internet for ages, I can't find what I need to do to allow the file to be streamed from a SQL Azure server that's not using active directory.

Answer (score 0):

Inevitably there was a tiny difference in the code between the local and Azure versions revealed by ProcMon. Fixed.